# why isn't laravel's php artisan serve server being accessible from the WWW on IIS

Tags: apache-2.2, php, windows-server-2008-r2, http, httpd

I have a laravel application running through the laravel artisan [server](http://laravel.com/docs/quick#installation):

```
 php artisan serve
```

and it works just fine if I go on my `localhost:8000`.. Further, I added an inbound rule in the IIS server like so:

> Control Panel -> Administrative Tools -> Windows Firewall with
>   Advanced Security, Inbound Rules. Make a new rule "Allow Port, TCP,
>   8000, All profiles

However for some reason i still can't access the website from the WWW (I did the exact same [steps](https://serverfault.com/questions/580692/how-to-make-webrick-server-accessible-on-the-web-on-windows-server-2008) for a webrick server (on the same machine) and things worked perfect).. any ideas?

Comment: Without knowing Laravel or `artisan`, my guess is that it's bound to `localhost` only by default and you have to configure it to handle non-local requests. Look up the docs of the system to check for this.

Comment: @SvW is correct.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

To get it to work outside of localhost, do `php artisan serve --host 0.0.0.0`

If you want it to work without specifying the port in the browser, `php artisan serve --host 0.0.0.0 --port 80`. `sudo` will likely be required.

Note: `php artisan serve` should **never** be used for production. It's for dev and demonstration only and won't be able to handle more than a person or two's worth of traffic.

Comment: ok sounds good.. indeed using your instructions i was able to view it from the WWW (ie mydomain.com:8080).. however i'm still wondering why i can't make apache actually serve it to the WWW? this is my specific scenario: running `artisan serve` makes it work just fine.. but then turning on apache gives me `page not found` errors.. i've created a sample laravel project using composer.. and that worked just fine even on apache.. however this project i actually copied over from another developer's machine.. i'm assuming it may have something to do with file permissions?

Comment: You're going to have to properly configure Apache to point at the right directory. See http://laravel.com/docs/installation#pretty-urls.

Comment: ok.. i changed `AllowOverride` to `All` in the `httpd.conf` file in the definition of the `DocumentRoot` as instructed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7859566/766570).. but that didn't work.. in the laravel website it says if that doesn't work try `Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On ..`.. but i'm not sure where to put those things? are they supposed to go to the same httpd.conf file as well?

Comment: Is your DocumentRoot pointed at the public directory?

Comment: it finally worked.. indeed it was an issue of enabling `mod_Rewrite`.. i did that manually by editing the `httpd.conf` file.. but noooo! i had to click on the stupid wamp gui menu and do it there *as well*.. did i mention i hate windows? but thanks bud!

Comment: AH!  Using `--host 0.0.0.0` did the trick.  Thank you @ceejayoz.

Comment: @colinhoernig Just remember to **never** use it for production.

Comment: @ceejayoz, yes, good call, thank you for the reminder.  I'm only using `artisan serve` inside of a Vagrant box for local development.